# Add swipe-gesture to images from the phone-gallery

Tags: android, swipe, gesture

So far I can retrieve the images from the gallery, and i can swipe. But I want the swipe to function to get to the next image of the gallery to the right and previous for the left. Please help me out.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.application.arkhid.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener, OnClickListener{

     private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
     private static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;
     private static final int HALF = 2;


     @Override

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     findViewById(R.id.browse_button).setOnClickListener(this);

     detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
     }


     @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
    }

     @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    InputStream stream = null;


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    try {
    stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

    Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_holder)).setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original,
    original.getWidth()/HALF, original.getHeight()/HALF, true));
    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (stream != null) {
      try {
            stream.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
    }


     @Override
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
         // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
          this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
     }

     @Override
     public void onSwipe(int direction) {

      String str = "";

      switch (direction) {

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";


      break;

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";

      break;

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN :  str = "Swipe Down";

      break;

      case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP :    str = "Swipe Up";

      break;

      }
       Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }   
}






import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;



public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

       public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
       public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
       public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
       public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

       public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
       public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
       public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

       private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
       private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
       private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
       private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 50;

   private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
   private boolean running      = true;
   private boolean tapIndicator = false;

   private Activity context;
   private GestureDetector detector;
   private SimpleGestureListener listener;

   public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

    this.context = context;
    this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
    this.listener = sgl;
   }

   public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

     if(!this.running)
    return; 

     boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

     if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
      event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);

     else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

       if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
         event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
       else if (result)
         event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
       else if(this.tapIndicator){
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        this.tapIndicator = false;
       }

     }
     //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
   }

   public void setMode(int m){
    this.mode = m;
   }

   public int getMode(){
    return this.mode;
   }

   public void setEnabled(boolean status){
    this.running = status;
   }

   public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
    this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
   }

   public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
    this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
   }

   public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
    this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
   }

   public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
    return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
   }

   public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
    return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
   }

   public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
    return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
   }

   @Override
       public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
         float velocityY) {

        final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
        final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

        if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
         return false;

        velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
              boolean result = false;

        if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
         if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
          this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
         else
          this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

         result = true;
        }
        else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
         if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
          this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
         else
          this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

         result = true;
        }

         return result;
       }

   @Override
   public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    this.tapIndicator = true;
    return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
    this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
    return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
    return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

    if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
       arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
       this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
    }  

    return false;
   }

      static interface SimpleGestureListener{
       void onSwipe(int direction);
       void onDoubleTap();
   }

}
```

Comment: I think you want something like a [Carousel layout](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/). Or [CoverFlow](https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Android Fullscreen Image Slider with Swipe and Pinch Zoom Gestures](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/)

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Yea i referred it but by using this i can only access the pictures which are on a particular folder on my SD card. i want to access all the images from the library.